# Google Maps API - Google Not Defined Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, backbone.js

I am try to use the Google Maps API in my Backbone application, but I get an error.  Here is my code:

```
var MyView = MyParrentView.extend({
    events: {
       //my events
    },
    initialize: function (options) {
        $('head').append('<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=MyAPIKey" type="text/javascript"></script>');  


   if (google != undefined) {
                google.load(
                    "earth",
                    "1",
                    {
                        "other_params":"sensor=false"
                    }
                );
            }
  }
 ,
```

At `if (google != undefined) {` line, I get the error: `ReferenceError: google is not defined`.  Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this or why this is happening?  I'm pretty new to using Google's API.

Thanks

Comment: Because you're not loading the script, merely adding a script tag to the HTML page?

Comment: oh, ok.  I thought that would load it.  How would I load it, using jquery/js/ then?  Thanks for the response!

Comment: You can use [$.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to load script.

Comment: `google` is not defined because it doesnot get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: The callback won't be executed until the script is loaded.

```
var MyView = MyParrentView.extend({
    events: {
       //my events
    },
    initialize: function (options) {
        $.ajax({url: 'https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=MyAPIKey&language=EN&callback=onGoogleMapsLoaded',dataType: 'script'});
    },

    onGoogleMapsLoaded : function(){
        if (google != undefined) {
            google.load(
                "earth",
                "1",
                {
                    "other_params":"sensor=false"
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```